# Fazer relacionamento (0,1) no mysql workbench

Tags: relacionamento, entidade-relacionamento, cardinalidade

Estou fazendo um projeto e comecei pela modelagem do banco foi tudo certo até o ponto de usuários que fiquei confuso.

Regras: admin geral(acesso a tudo), admin empresa(acesso a todos os eventos da empresa) e o usuário(acesso a apenas um evento).
Na tabela usuários quero deixar:

1. usuário A associado a uma empresa.
2. usuário B não estar associado a nenhuma empresa.(administradores)
3. usuário C estar associado a uma empresa e a um evento.

nesse caso preciso ter uma chave estrangeira com a tabela **empresa** e **evento**.
Mas desse jeito fico preso a sempre associar um **admin** para uma empresa e um evento. Como resolver isso, removendo as chaves?

Comment: da uma estudada sobre **tabela associativa** que resolve seu caso

Comment: ta ficou muito bruto o comentario, vou postar uma resposta para explicar como se faz

Comment: criar uma tabela N:M?

Comment: Depende do resto dos relacionamentos que você vai precisar.

Comment: Empresa e eventos se relaciona com outras por chave estrangeira.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA se eu fizer associativa criando uma tabela para id de evento, id de empresa, id de usuario eu não estaria obrigando a associar um usuario a pelo menos um evento e uma empresa??

Comment: Thalles Se a tabela não contiver nenhuma entrada com aquele ID de usuário, ele não está relacionado a nada. Mesmo assim, acho mais legal você explicar como funciona a relação entre empresas e eventos também, pra facilitar pra quem for responder.

Comment: @Bacco adicionei informações na pergunta, e vi a resposta pensei nisso criar uma tabela com as relações sem chaves mas achei que seria errado dessa maneira mas vlw pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Vou fazer a associativa entre a tabela usuario e a tabela empresa e verá que o mesmo caso para a tabela evento.

Primeiro vou colocar o código de exemplo

```
CREATE TABLE `teste`.`tab_usuario` (
`usu_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`usu_id`)  COMMENT '');

CREATE TABLE `teste`.`tab_empresa` (
`emp_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
`emp_nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)  COMMENT '');

INSERT INTO `teste`.`tab_empresa` (`emp_id`, `emp_nome`) VALUES ('1', 'empresa1');
INSERT INTO `teste`.`tab_empresa` (`emp_id`, `emp_nome`) VALUES ('2', 'empresa2');

INSERT INTO `teste`.`tab_usuario` (`usu_id`, `nome`) VALUES ('1', 'john');
INSERT INTO `teste`.`tab_usuario` (`usu_id`, `nome`) VALUES ('2', 'noah');

CREATE TABLE `teste`.`rel_usuario_empresa` (
`usu_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`emp_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`usu_id`, `emp_id`)  COMMENT '',
UNIQUE INDEX `usu_id_UNIQUE` (`usu_id` ASC)  COMMENT '');
```

Essa tabela associativa `rel_usuario_empresa` esta considerando que 1 usuario será único `UNIQUE INDEX usu_id_UNIQUE` para garantir que o usuário cadastrado ali não seja duplicado ou inserido em duas empresas.

```
INSERT INTO `teste`.`rel_usuario_empresa` (`usu_id`, `emp_id`) VALUES ('1', '1');
```

E para fazer uma consulta deixo o exemplo abaixo:

```
select
    u.nome, -- nome na tab_usuario
    e.emp_nome -- nome da empresa tab_empresa
from tab_usuario u, rel_usuario_empresa r, tab_empresa e -- tabelas a serem consultadas
where   u.usu_id=1  -- filtro do usuario codigo 1
        and u.usu_id = r.usu_id -- relacao entre tab_usuario e rel_usuario_empresa atraves
        and r.emp_id = e.emp_id -- relacao entre rel_usuario_empresa e tab_empresa
```

Nos termos **john** esta associado a empresa1 enquanto **noah** não esta associado a nenhuma empresa, se tentar inserir **john** novamente na rel_usuario_empresa com a mesma empresa ou outra empresa que seja o relacionamento já irá garantir que isso não aconteça.

usuário C seria a mesma problemática então seria criar outra associativa, e registra-lo tanto na tab_empresa quando na  tab_evento e suas respectivas tabelas associativas.

Comment: SneepS só pra concluir então farei uma tabela que não estão relacionadas por chaves estrangerias seria uma forma "simbólica" desse relacionamento? ou estou errado?

Comment: rsrsr não sei o que quis dizer com simbólica, mas essa tabela que irá garantir as regras

Comment: Vlw mam obrigado